# How can I send data by a form without an input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send data to another html file by a form, but I don't want to use an input field. I just want to send an ID to the other file. How can I add the ID to the URL, when I want to get the data by location.search?

```
<form method="GET" action="secondHTML.html">
     <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="submit" name="ID" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Add `value="something"` to your `button` and you will have `secondHTML.html?ID=something` in the URL.

Comment: What's the point with a form if all you want is to send an id. Using a link with a query string or route will do that alone.

Comment: ok, but how I'm able to don't  send it by an fixed link ? I just want to use the filename.

Comment: why ask why, SO was not meant to be a ridicule people for their questions, and no matter how "helpful" you think you are in answering a question with another question, if you don't know, just don't answer. No need to be inconsiderate. Curiosity should not be discouraged. And everyone was a beginner at some time.

Answer (score 3):

You can send form data by using an [`<input type="hidden">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden), which can be used to send information without the user being able to see or modify it.

```html
<form method="GET" action="secondHTML.html">
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="value" />
    <button type="submit" name="ID" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```